# How to transfer file using POST method in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I want to transfer the image by using the POST method

```
var queryString = querystring.stringify({
    "category": "1",
    "photo": "/home/dmitriy/image2.jpg" // HOW I CAN TO TRANSFER THIS IMAGE?
});

var options = {
    hostname: 'dimonchikone.ucoz.net',
    port: 80,
    path: '/uapi/photo',
    method: method,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': queryString.length
    }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write(queryString);
req.end();
```

but not understand how? In php when i use curl i just write next code

```
"photo": "@/home/dmitriy/image2.jpg"
```

How i can transfer this file in node.js? I want transfers image and then get using PHP $_FILE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the `request` [module](https://github.com/request/request), it becomes trivial:

```
fs.createReadStream('/home/dmitriy/image2.jpg').pipe(request.put('http://dimonchikone.ucoz.net/uapi/photo/image2.jpg'))
```